# Removing a codesandbox.io sandbox

Tags: codesandbox

I have create several sandboxes that are no longer of use and are cluttering up my dashboard. I would like to remove these sandboxes. How can I remove a sandbox?

Answer (score 8):

At this time: Monday Oct. 10 2022
Deleting is a 2-step process:

1. The last entry in the '...' 3 dots menu in the general sandbox overview has an 'Archive Sandbox' menu entry.
2. In the codesandbox.io side bar, selecting the 'Archive' entry opens a selection of archived sandboxes with a different '...' 3 dots menu with entries for 'Recover Sandbox' or 'Delete Permanently'.

Comment: Well this is a stupid way of having to delete something. Thanks for the answer. I've always had a love/hate relationship with codesandbox but I don't really have words for how unintuitive this new change is.

Comment: The way them interfaces keep changing right? But codesandbox.io is still awesome. I have found so many helpful solutions there and here on stackoverflow.com which is also uber awesome. Thank you for responding to my solution! Cool name EndlessCodebase

Answer (score 1):

On the dashboard, each sandbox has a "hamburger/three-dots" menu - of which the last entry is "delete sandbox".

Comment: Could you rephrase this to make more of an answering impression? Currently it risks being mistaken for a clarification question...

Comment: Yeah, just didn't want to appear insulting to OP.  Balance.

Comment: A noble cause. But I like it better now.

Comment: This does not seem to work for forked sandbox

Answer (score 1):

As of Dec 1 2022: at the bottom of the Sandbox info panel, there's a `Delete sandbox` command.
To show the Sandbox info panel, click on the parcel-shaped icon at the top of the left icon bar.

[image]